# How to show $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln^{2}x\:\mathrm{d}x=\gamma ^{2}+\frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}$?

Tags: integration

How to show this equation below is true?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln^{2}x\:\mathrm{d}x=\gamma ^{2}+\frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}$$

Where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant....

Comment: Your problem is exactly number $(2)$ in this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188418/elementary-derivation-of-certian-identites-related-to-the-riemannian-zeta-functi). I already gave a technique for solving it.

Comment: I found another thread in which a more complete answer is given. So I guess I'm OK with this thread being closed, even if I don't think it was actually closed for the reason stated. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394227/how-to-prove-that-int-0-infty-log2x-e-kxdx-dfrac-pi26k-df?lq=1

Comment: @RandomVariable: Are you sure it is 90% of the problem? I already gave him a hint in the note to find $\Gamma''(s)$! Your answer does answer the question. In case he has a problem with $\Gamma''(s)$ he can ask a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, the integral evaluates to $\Gamma''(1)$.

Recall the digamma and trigamma functions:

$$\psi_{0} (x) = \frac{d}{dx} \ln \Gamma(x) = \frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$$

$$\psi_{1}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \psi_{0}(x) = \frac{\Gamma''(x)\Gamma(x)- (\Gamma'(x))^{2}}{\Gamma^{2}(x)}$$

Then

$$\psi_{1}(1) = \frac{\Gamma''(1)\Gamma(1) + (\Gamma'(1))^{2}}{\Gamma^{2}(1)} = \Gamma''(1) - (\Gamma'(1))^{2} $$

The digamma and trigamma functions also have series definitions (which can be derived from the infinite product representation of the gamma function):

$$ \psi_{0}(x) = - \gamma + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+x}\Big)$$

$$\psi_{1}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+x)^{2}}$$

So

$$ \psi_{1}(1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} = \zeta(2)  = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$$

And

$$\Gamma'(1) = \psi_{0}(1) \Gamma(1) = \psi_{0}(1) = - \gamma +  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) = - \gamma$$

Therefore,

$$\Gamma''(1) = \psi_{1}(1) + (\Gamma'(1))^{2} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} + \gamma^{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

For Real-Valued $s>0$, consider the well-known $$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt}$$ Now differentiating twice with respect to $s$ and by the Dominated convergence theorem, which allows us to differentiate inside the integral we have that $$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial s^{2}}\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{ln^{2}(t)\cdot t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt}$$ plugging in $s=1$ yields our disired result. 
The derivatives of the gamma function can be expressed as polygamma functions, where $$\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}=\psi(s)$$

Answer (score 2):

Related problems: [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188418/elementary-derivation-of-certian-identites-related-to-the-riemannian-zeta-functi), [II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340033/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-left-frac-log-x-arctan-xx-right2). Recalling the Mellin transform of a function $f$

> $$ F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1} f(x)dx $$

which gives

> $$ F''(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\ln(x)^2 f(x) dx .$$

Now, for your case, taking $f(x)=e^{-x}$ which has its Mellin transform equals to $F(s)=\Gamma(s)$, where $\Gamma(s)$ is the gamma function, gives

> $$ F''(s) = \Gamma''(s) \longrightarrow (*) .$$

Taking the limit of $(*)$ as $s\to 1$ gives the desired result.

**Note:**

> $$ \Gamma'(s) = \Gamma(s)\psi(s). $$

Comment: You seem to use Mellin transforms a lot to solve difficult integrals.  Do you have any good literature on them that you recommend?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Integration by parts.

$$f(x)=\ln^2 x$$
$$g^{\prime}(x)=e^{-x}$$

Comment: if possible, please write down essential details.

Comment: Given that the indefinite integral isn't elementary, it's hard to see how this approach could be made to work.