# Reference request for a Meijer G identity

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

I found the following identity while I was working on [a recent question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996559/194117):
For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, 
$$G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)=\gamma\ln{z}+\frac12\ln^2(z)-z\,_3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-z)+\frac{\gamma^2}2+\frac{\pi^2}{12}.\tag{1}$$
WolframAlpha [confirms it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MeijerG%5B%7B%7B%7D,%7B1,1%7D%7D,%7B%7B0,0,0%7D,%7B%7D%7D,x%5D), but I couldn't find the formula stated anywhere online from my searches. Has this result already been discovered? If so, could someone point me in the right direction? I've made a proof for the identity, which I have included below. There's likely a more elegant, succinct proof for it, but this is what I could muster using my current knowledge.

> **Proof**: Taking the derivative gives us $\frac{d}{dz}G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)=-\frac{\Gamma(0,z)}z$, from which we can state 
>   $$-\int\frac{\Gamma(0,z)}z dz=G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)+C.\tag{2}$$ 
>   Since [$\Gamma(0,z)=E_1(z)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4#E4), we can use the [series expansion for $E_1(z)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6#E2), *which converges for all complex $z$*, to rewrite $(2)$ as 
>   $$\begin{align}\int\frac{\gamma+\ln{z}}z dz-\int\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-z)^{k-1}}{k\,k!}dz&=G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)+C\\ \gamma\ln{z}+\frac12\ln^2(z)-z\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-z)^{k-1}}{k^2\,k!}+C_0&=G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)+C\\ \gamma\ln{z}+\frac12\ln^2(z)-z\,_3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-z)&=G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)+C^*,\tag{3}\label{3}\end{align}$$ 
>   where $C_0$ is a second constant of integration and $C^*=C-C_0$. In order to maintain both equivalence and continuity in $(3)$, $C^* $ can only hold one value--we must therefore solve for $C^*$. One method of doing so involves evaluating $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{-\Gamma(0,z)}z dz$. Because $z$ is positive along the given interval, this can be equivalently expressed as 
>   $$\int_1^\infty\frac{-\Gamma(0,z)}z dz=\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{Ei}(-z)}z dz.\tag{4}$$ 
>   Repeated application of integration by parts yields 
>   $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{Ei}(-z)}z dz=-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln{z}}{ze^z}dz=\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln{z}}{ze^z}dz-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^2(z)}{e^z}dz,$$ 
>   from which we can infer that 
>   $$\begin{align}-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln{z}}{ze^z}dz=-\frac12\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^2(z)}{e^z}dz&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(z)}{e^z}dz-\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2(z)}{e^z}dz\\&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(z)}{e^z}dz-\frac{\gamma^2}2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\tag{5}\end{align}$$ 
>   ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/753804/194117)). After integration by parts and manipulation of series, we get 
>   $$\begin{align}\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(z)}{e^z}dz&=-\frac12\left[\frac{\ln^2(z)}{e^z}\right]_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{\ln{z}}{ze^z}dz\\&=-\frac12\left[\frac{\ln^2(z)}{e^z}\right]_0^1+\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k z^{k-1}\ln{z}}{k!}dz\\&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k z^{k-1}\ln{z}}{k!}dz\\&=\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-z)^k\ln{z}}{k\,k!}\right]_0^1+\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-z)^{k-1}}{k\,k!}dz\\&=\left[z\,_3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-z)\right]_0^1\\&={}_3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-1).\tag{6}\end{align}$$ 
>   Putting together everything we have so far, we arrive at 
>   $$\int_1^\infty\frac{-\Gamma(0,z)}z dz={}_3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-1)-\frac{\gamma^2}2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.\tag{7}$$ 
>   Notice that $-{}_3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-1)$ is the value obtained from the left-hand side of $\eqref{3}$ when $z=1$. Using both this observation and the first fundamental theorem of calculus, we can deduce that 
>   $$\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(\gamma\ln{z}+\frac12\ln^2(z)-z\,_3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-z)\right)=-\frac{\gamma^2}2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.$$ 
>   Furthermore, 
>   $$\lim_{z\to\infty}G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)=-C^*-\frac{\gamma^2}2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.\tag{8}$$ 
>   From [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/21/02/07/0002/), we know that 
>   $$\int_z^\infty\frac{\Gamma(0,x)}xdx=\int_z^\infty\frac{1}xG_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(x\left|\begin{array}{c}1\\0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)dx=G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right).\tag{9}$$ 
>   This implies 
>   $$\lim_{z\to\infty}G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)=\lim_{z\to\infty}\left[\int_z^\infty\frac{1}xG_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(x\left|\begin{array}{c}1\\0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)dx\right]=0,\tag{10}$$ 
>   and we may now conclude with 
>   $$C^*=-\frac{\gamma^2}2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.\tag{11}$$ 
>   Using $(11)$, we can rewrite $\eqref{3}$ as the identity 
>   $$G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(z\left|\begin{array}{c}1,1\\0,0,0\\\end{array}\right.\right)=\gamma\ln{z}+\frac12\ln^2(z)-z\,_3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-z)+\frac{\gamma^2}2+\frac{\pi^2}{12}.\tag{12}$$ 
>   Q.E.D.