# Integral $\int_0^\infty \ln x\,\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) \frac{x^4+3\alpha x^2- 1}{x^6}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$I:=\int_0^\infty \ln x\,\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) \frac{x^4+3\alpha x^2- 1}{x^6}dx=\frac{(1+\alpha)\sqrt{2\alpha^3 \pi}}{2\sqrt[\alpha]e},\qquad \alpha>0.$$

This one looks very nice.  It has stumped me.

Differentiation with respect to parameter does not seem to work either if I try $I(\alpha)$ and $I'(\alpha)$. at x=0 there seems to be a problem with the integrand also however I am not sure how to go about using this. Perhaps we could try and use a series expansion for $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  x^n /n!$, however the function $e^{-1/x^2}$ is well known that its taylor series is zero despite the function not being.

Comment: Where on earth are you getting these from?

Comment: I already asked you this question to which you never answered : are you planning to produce a textbook with "nice" integrals ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I did respond, I apologize you never saw it.  No this is just for everybody on math stack.  I am integrals, so I contribute integrals for us all.  I do not plan on making a textbook with nice integrals, those already exist!

Comment: @nbubis  I have many variations of these kinds....Once you can solve one, you try and generalize.  I used to love these as a kid, i'm digging them all out again

Comment: @Integrals. Thanks for answering. May I ask you where you find these integrands and results ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have books of my notes as a math student, we used to study integration very seriously. I have about 10 variations of this integral in my notes from the 70/80's. Now I am old.  I do check the results numerically

Comment: I fyou are old, what am I ? My adress is Jurassic.Park

Comment: To evaluate the last three integrals you can use the technique in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188418/elementary-derivation-of-certian-identites-related-to-the-riemannian-zeta-functi/188437#188437).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici if there are infinitely many primes, surely the number 72 is quite small.  Thank you for your answer

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: You have energy more than we do.

Comment: $[Energy,More]\neq 0$ @MhenniBenghorbal where [F,G]=FG-GF.

Comment: I suggest substituting $y=x-1/x$.

Comment: Should the $3\alpha x$ actually be $3\alpha x^2$?

Comment: @ChenWang Yes sorry typo from the other post , it should be $3\alpha x^2$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the $3\alpha x$ term is in fact $3\alpha x^2$ (otherwise the numerical results do not match).

$$\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^\infty \ln x\,\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) \frac{x^4+3\alpha x^2- 1}{x^6}dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \ln x\, d\left(-\alpha x^{-3}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)\right)\\
&=-\alpha\left(\left.\frac{\ln x}{x^3}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)\right|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^3}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) d\,\ln x\right)\\
&=\alpha\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^4}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right) dx\\
&=\alpha\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^4}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx+\underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^4}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx}_{x\to1/x}\right) \\
&=\alpha\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^4}\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx+\int_1^0 -x^2\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx\right) \\
&=\alpha\int_0^1 (x^2+x^{-4})\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^4}{2\alpha x^2}\right)dx\\
&=\alpha\int_0^1 (x^2-1+x^{-2})\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{(x-1/x)^2}{2\alpha }\right)d(x-1/x)\\
&=\alpha e^{-1/\alpha}\int_0^1 (1+(x-1/x)^2)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-1/x)^2}{2\alpha }\right)d(x-1/x)\\
&=\alpha e^{-1/\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^0 (1+y^2)\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2\alpha }\right)dy\\
&=\alpha e^{-1/\alpha}(\alpha+1)\sqrt{\frac{\alpha\pi}{2}}.
\end{align*}$$